# How to dispose the controller for custom widget?

Tags: flutter

I have created my custom Widget that uses a controller like TextField.

```
Widget textField({...}) {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  return TextFormField(controller: controller, ...);
}
```

The main page uses this widget like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class mainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const mainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<mainPage> createState() => _mainPageState();
}

class _mainPageState extends State<mainPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              textField(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The main page doesn't see the controller from textWidget. How to dispose of this controller?

Or I must create the controller on the main page and send this controller by using a parameter like this.

```
Widget textField({required TextEditingController controller}) {
  return TextFormField(controller: controller, ...);
}
```

Is it work?
Another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that in two ways

1. Make the `textField` widget stateful and dispose the controller on onDispose
2. create the text editing controller in the `mainPage` and pass it to the `textField` widget

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell me what most people do? I want to do it according to common standards.

Comment: IF you want to reuse the widget everywhere, it would be best to make it a separate stateful widget and pass the callback and other attributes you need. I go with this in my projects

Comment: please mark as accepted if the answer helped